# NPE in java.util.LinkedList addBefore method

Tags: java, serialization, weblogic, java-6

Somehow, I'm getting a null pointer exception here with JDK 1.6.0_14:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
LinkedList<MyObject> list = (LinkedList<MyObject>) session.getAttribute(MY_LIST_KEY);
....
list.addFirst( new MyObject(str1, str2, map) );
```

Then, I get this:

```
 at java.util.LinkedList.addBefore(LinkedList.java:779)
```

Here's the method:

```
private Entry<E> addBefore(E e, Entry<E> entry) {
    Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(e, entry, entry.previous);
    newEntry.previous.next = newEntry;//this line NPEs
    newEntry.next.previous = newEntry;
    size++;
    modCount++;
    return newEntry;
}
```

which is called by

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    addBefore(e, header.next);
}
```

Is there any weird way the list can be serialized/deserialized to break the header entry to cause this to happen? I don't see how this could possibly be failing.

Here's the serialization methods for `LinkedList`

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException {
    // Write out any hidden serialization magic
    s.defaultWriteObject();

    // Write out size
    s.writeInt(size);

    // Write out all elements in the proper order.
    for (Entry e = header.next; e != header; e = e.next)
        s.writeObject(e.element);
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
    throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read in any hidden serialization magic
    s.defaultReadObject();

    // Read in size
    int size = s.readInt();

    // Initialize header
    header = new Entry<E>(null, null, null);
    header.next = header.previous = header;

    // Read in all elements in the proper order.
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        addBefore((E)s.readObject(), header);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be improper sharing of the List across multiple threads.  I would guess the list is being simultaneously modified by two different threads.

Comment: How would that invalidate the head element? I don't see a code path here that ever lets header be null, ever.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall, If 2 threads concurrently call `readObject()` and `addFirst()` and the 1st blocks right at `header.next = /* right here*/ header.previous = header;` you would have such a case.

Comment: Hm, that seems reasonable. I'll switch to a synchronized list and retest. Good freakin' catch.

Answer (score -2):

Most probably, `(LinkedList<MyObject>) session.getAttribute(MY_LIST_KEY)` returned `null`.
**Update:** As correctly pointed out in comments, `null` can not be returned by `getAttribute()` here, otherwise stacktrace wouldn't point into internals of `LinkedList`. So, my suggestion is wrong.

Comment: the stacktrace would point at his own code then, not at a line in the LinkedList class.

Comment: if list would be null then the NPE could not come from list addBefore() method.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that :) Please, disregard my answer.